# XSLT Transform not showing in the local machine browser

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to populate a template from some data in the XML file. I tried to put it using XSLT on the client. But is not working. So I started with the basic.

Trying to show the XSLT transform data and exactly did the same thing showed in w3schools but as soon as I give the reference of the stylesheet in the XML file, it does not show anything in the browser.

cdcatalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl" ?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>


</catalog>
```

cdcatalog.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
<tr>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "*it does not show anything in the browser.*" Which browser is "*the browser*"?

Comment: Chrome. Also it shows the data in internet explorer but does not show in the correct format

Comment: Do a search for `[xslt]  chrome`. -- P.S. "*does not show in the correct format*" is not a useful description of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps opening the HTML file in the browser using a "file:/" URL rather than an "http:/" URL? Many browsers won't then allow you to access a stylesheet using a relative URI because of concerns about cross-site scripting security violations. Try it over an HTTP connection.